# Файловый ввод-вывод объектов класса

Tags: c++, файлы

Доброго времени суток. 
Есть класс, есть менюшка для работы с классом (добавление, вывод объектов класса, удаление) 
Каким образом организовать запись и чтение полей класса?? (Можно и бинарный файл)

Т.е. мне идейно не понятно как это будет работать :(

Думаю что взять блоковую запись-вывод. (Один объект - одна строка) 
Но не понятно, как связать всё это с тем что я уже имею.

Буду благодарен если кто-то прояснит.

Ну, тут кода многовато.

Если очень кратко, то как-то так:

```
while ( x != EXIT)
{
    cin.clear();
    menu();
    cin >> x;
    switch (x)
    {
        case ADD: 
        {
            MemPtr=AddMemory(MemPtr); // выделение памяти под объект, если объектов 0, выделяется 1 ячейка, если уже существуют объекты - то выделяется на 1 больше, а старый массив перезаписывается. Там же вызывается функция для заполнения полей объекта.
            system("cls");
            break;
        }
        case SHOW:
        {
            MemPtr->ShowM(MemPtr); 
            break;
        }
        case DELETE:
        {
            MemPtr=Delete(MemPtr);
            break;
        }
        case EXIT:
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
return 0;
Members * AddMemory(Members * ptr)
{
    //FILE *in;
    //if (!(in = fopen("xx.txt", "wb")))
    {
        printf("Open file failed.\n");
    }
    if (Members::exist == 0)
    {
        ptr = new Members[Members::exist + 1]; 
        fwrite(ptr, sizeof(Members), 1, in);
        fclose(in);

    }
    else
    {
        Members *tmp = new Members[Members::exist+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < Members::exist; ++i)
        {
            tmp[i] = ptr[i];
        }
        delete[] ptr;
        ptr = tmp;
    }
    ptr[Members::exist].AddMember();
    Members::exist++;
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: Запишите каждое поле отдельно. Почему так не годится?

Comment: У меня массив объектов.. Каждое поле в отдельную строку записывать?

Comment: Приведите пример кода, что и куда нужно сохранять. Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Добавил сверху. Но как-то кривовато вышло :(

Comment: Почему вы не хотите использовать стандартные потоки ввыода/вывода в `c++`? Они удобные. Я не совсем понимаю, что такое `AddMemory`, `MemPtr`, `ShowM`. Вам нужно многократно записывать данные в файл?

Comment: Есть меню:
1. Добавить объект. 
2. Удалить объект
3. Просмотреть

При нажатии на 1, выделяется память под массив объектов класса Member. (вверху добавил функцию)
На 2-ку - просматриваю все объекты. 
При нажатии на 3-ку, по заданному номеру могу удалять объект.

Что нужно:
Создать файл, в него записать поля класса. Закрыл программу - открываю файл, считываю что там есть. Каким-то образом работаю с объектами, по окончанию выгружаю их обратно в файл.

Comment: Не вставляйте тег <code>, когда хотите добавить вашу программу. В меню (над полем с вводимым сообщением) есть специальный тег, кодорый позволяет выделить Вашу программу необходимым образом.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. С большего сделал :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пусть у нас есть класс `A`. Тогда, записывать будем каждое поле класса отдельно. В силу того, что есть строгая последовательность, то при считывании мы однозначно восстановим наши данные. Это легко сделать:

```
class A {
    p1 int;
    p2 int;
    p3 int;
}

void WriteToFile(vector <A> vec, string pathToFile) {
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(pathToFile);
    fout << vec.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        fout << vec[i].p1 << vec[i].p2 << vec[i].p3;
    }
    fout.close();
}

vector <A> vec ReadFromFile(string pathToFile) {
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(pathToFile);
    int n;
    fin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        fin >> vec[i].p1 >> vec[i].p2 >> vec[i].p3;
    }
    fin.close();
}




void WriteToFile(A *vec, int n, string pathToFile) {
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(pathToFile);
    fout << n;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        fout << vec[i].p1 << vec[i].p2 << vec[i].p3;
    }
    fout.close();
}

int *A ReadFromFile(int &n, string pathToFile) {
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(pathToFile);
    int n;
    A *vec = new A[n];
    fin >> n;        
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        fin >> vec[i].p1 >> vec[i].p2 >> vec[i].p3;
    }
    fin.close();
}
```

Небольшое пояснение к коду. Будем поочерёдно перебирать элементы нашего массива и записывать их в файл. На каждой итерации будем поэлементно писать поля класса `A`.

Замечу, что коль скоро Вы поэлементно считываете и обрабатываете элементы массива, имеет смысл каждый обработанный элемент сразу записывать в файл, если число элементов достаточно большое. Это следует предпринимать, если все считываемые элементы в память не помещаются.

Comment: Спасибо, векторы к сожалению использовать нельзя. Буду пытаться под себя адаптировать :)
Идейно мне это как-то так делать ?
1. При запуске, пишу, мол файл загружен (гружу из файла объекты в память) 
2. Что-то делаю с объектами в памяти
3. Выгружаю обратно в файл. 

Или мне с одним объектом лучше работать в памяти?

Comment: Посмотрите мою правку. Если что-то непонятно, поясните что.

Comment: @TorSen: А почему нельзя использовать векторы?

Comment: @VladD, вероятно, задание такое.

Comment: Если это учебное задание, то с ним надо справляться самому. В реальном программировании таких ограничений не будет.

Comment: Именно учебное, поэтому и приходится отказываться от векторов.
"то с ним надо справляться самому." ну, так я ведь не прошу за меня сделать, только подсказать идейно, дабы потом еще раз не переписывать и без того "макаронный код"

Не совсем понятно для чего переменная n. Идейно - всё понятно.